# PID controllers simulink

Tags: simulink, pid-controller

Labview uses P= 4.3 , I = 0.12, D =0.03  ( I collected data)
Simulink uses P = 110 , I = 15, D= 40
Step response is almost the same. 
My question is how I can set my simulink to use the same PID controllers as in Labview?

Comment: They have to be different implementations of the PID (or different plants).  Is one parallel form and one series form?

Comment: They use the same transfer function, I'm sure about that.  What do you mean by "different implementation, parallel or series form"? Interestingly, I've been looking online, and any time simulink is used for LC, PID values are about the same that I used. And their labview is small.They don't explain further . But im sure theres a lógic behind

Comment: PID's can be implemented in different, but equivalent, ways.  The gains will have different values depending on the form of the implementation.  See for instance [Standard versus parallel (ideal) PID form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Standard_versus_parallel_(ideal)_PID_form)